# How to get back to Apache 2.2 after accidentally installing Apache 2.4?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu-12.04

I have carelessly installed the following package: `ppa:ondrej/php5` on a Ubuntu 12.04 LTS server.

It turns out that it comes with an upgrade from Apache 2.2 to Apache 2.4, breaking the existing installation.

I've already removed the package, but that was not enough to restore the site. What more do I need to do to recover?

Answer (score 1):

You should be a little more clear about what is going wrong now; post output from `apache2ctl -t` and relevant lines from the Apache error log.

if by "I've removed the package", you mean the `ppa:ondrej/php5` one, then you still have to remove apache-2.4 and install 2.2. Before doing this, I would backup `/etc/apache2` (`cp -a /etc/apache2 /etc/apache2.bak`). Then, it may still not work because the configuration files may have changed. It may be wise to look at `/etc/apache2` and see if you can see `.dist-old` (or something) files. Those would/could be the config files as they were before you installed 2.4.

BTW, do you have backups and/or have your `/etc` in git or bzr? Then it's easy enough to restore /etc/apache2.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Yes, I have backups of /etc in git, and backing out was the first thing I tried, but without success. To me, it looks like upgrading is a one-way street. I struggled for a long time with an Apache that was part 2.2 and 2.4. I finally managed resolving it by doing a "proper" upgrade of Apache to 2.4. It's been a hard day.